# can i use the name of subclass in my superclass?

Tags: java, subclass, superclass

I have superclass, that looks like:

```
 public abstract class Fish {

 protected int size;

 protected float weight;

 //constructor

 public Fish(int s, float w) {
 size = aSize;weight = aWeight;}
```

and I have 2 subclasses of this superclass. First one:

```
 public class SomeFish extends Fish{

 //constructor

 public SomeFish(int s, float w) {

 super(s, w) }
```

Second one:

```
public class AnotherFish extends Fish{

 //constructor

 public AnotherFish(int s, float w) {

 super(s, w) }
```

What I have to do is to write a String toString method in the **Fish class**, that would return something like: A 12 cm 0.5 *here should be proper type of fish* (AnotherFish or SomeFish). Can I do it without making string toString method abstract and implement string toString method in both SomeFish and AnotherFish classes?

Comment: toString exists in the Object class so you don't need to make it abstract. simply override it on any class where needed.

Comment: @KugathasanAbimaran I need to return string with the name of the type of fish, if it's AnotherFish or SomeFish.

Comment: @SlipperySeal i have to make it abstract :/

Comment: nobody has to do anything maaaaan :)

Comment: @SlipperySeal computer science assignment, i haaaave to

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Refer to the class of the `this` instance, which will be the *actual* class (possibly a subclass):

```
public abstract class Fish {

    // rest of class omitted

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "A " + size + "cm, " + weight + "kg " + getClass().getSimpleName();
    }
}
```

The call `getClass().getSimpleName()` will return the String `"AnotherFish"` etc.

No need to define anything in a subclass to make this work.

Comment: that what i needed, I  wish I had seen it in time) Thank you!

Comment: Seen it in time??? This answer was posted 10 minutes after your question was. That's not fast enough?

Comment: sorry, I didn't mean that.. It was my fault, that I haven't seet it